# Undocumented behaviour in C#

Tags: c#, undocumented-behavior

Unlike C++, C, etc there are very few undocumented behavior in C# as opposed to the .NET framework.

All programmers are aware about the dangers comparing floating point numbers…

When doing a code review it is often useful to have a checklist, one par to the checklist normally contains “undocumented behaviour” that shop be spotted and removed.

What undocumented behaviour should be on such a check list for C# and what version(s) of C# are there a program in.

---

This question was prompted by “[How are ambiguous enum values resolved in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852609/how-are-ambiguous-enum-values-resolved-in-c)?”, I was surprised by the answer as in my many years as a C# programmer I do not recall coming across any bugs in C# code due to the use of undefined behaviours apart from float point numbers.

I recall from my distant past when I write C++ code, that coding standards etc often had lists of undefined behaviours to be avoided, but have never seen such a list for C#.

Comment: Dont you `undefined` behavior?

Comment: you haven't even specified the .NET/C# version

Comment: I am not getting the question, can any one explain in comment by giving example or something :)

Comment: @Jageen, I have added more details to the quesion

Comment: I would have to disagree with "All programmers are aware about the dangers comparing floating point numbers" unless there are some `<sarcasm>` tags missing from your question. Given people keep asking questions about why floats in (pick a language/enivornment) are buggy...

Comment: Bit of a stretch to say that this is "primarily opinion based"? If a particular behaviour is not defined in the C# Spec, that is not based on opinion, it is fact. I think this would have produced some useful discussion.

Comment: @dtsg I don't know, there seems to be a difference of opinion as to whether the enum behaviour linked is documented or not.

Comment: C++ documents a lot of behavior as 'undefined'.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever,   I would not call these people "programmers"!